# How to close expanded table view cell programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have two tabs in a view controller: on click of each tab, different data is displayed in a table view with cells that expand and close on click.

The problem is that when I'm in tab A, and expand a cell there, then go and click on tab B, loading new data, that cell is still expanded. How do I close it programatically?

I'm using the `FZAccordionTableView` subclass to perform the expansions.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(FZAccordionTableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    HeaderView *view = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:kAccordionHeaderViewReuseIdentifier];
    if (listOfCategoryWhichHaveItems.count > 0) {
        if (arrCategory.count > 0) {
            arrCategory1  = _btnProduct.selected == YES ? [arrCategory objectAtIndex:0] : [arrCategory objectAtIndex:1];
            NSDictionary *dict = arrCategory1[section];
            view.lblHeaderTitel.text = [dict valueForKey:kCategory];
            bool isSelected = [tableView isSectionOpen:section];
        }
    }
    return view;
}

#pragma mark - <FZAccordionTableViewDelegate> -

- (void)tableView:(FZAccordionTableView *)tableView willOpenSection:(NSInteger)section withHeader:(UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)header {
    loadFirstTime = false;
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    if (listOfCategoryWhichHaveItems.count > 0) {
        _sectionNumber = &section;
        NSDictionary *dict = listOfCategoryWhichHaveItems[section];
        [self setDataAccordingToCategories:[dict valueForKey:kCategory]];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(FZAccordionTableView *)tableView didOpenSection:(NSInteger)section withHeader:(UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)header {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set keepOneSectionOpen property of your table to No on clicking the tab B.

```
Yourtable.keepOneSectionOpen = No;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `FZAccordionTableView` [GitHub repo](https://github.com/fuzz-productions/FZAccordionTableView/blob/158a07be2528b6aac518e27876981d19867d57c6/FZAccordionTableView/FZAccordionTableView.m#L376) i found this method:

```
- (void)closeSection:(NSInteger)section withHeaderView:(nullable FZAccordionTableViewHeaderView *)sectionHeaderView
```

That will probably do what you want, it is however not declared in the [header file](https://github.com/fuzz-productions/FZAccordionTableView/blob/master/FZAccordionTableView/FZAccordionTableView.h) so you can't call it directly.

You can however clone the repo, add the line to the header file, add + commit + push to your fork. Then use [that repo](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#from-a-podspec-in-the-root-of-a-library-repo) in your Podfile (or however you're using the library right now) so you're using your fork of the framework, then you can call the method.

Answer (score 0):

On click of each tab, i used this 
[_tblProductServies closeAllSectionsExcept:-1]; 
its working fine now, thanks for all.